# Windows 10 Storage Spaces recover data from 2-way mirror

Tags: windows, hard-drive-failure, storage-spaces

I got some serious problem with my backup:

Due to faulty power supply, 3 out of my 4 HDDs died.... Since I did set up a storage pool with "2-way mirroring", I was quite optimistic to recover most of the data because the biggest HDD survived (so there should be ~3.5 TB data on that drive).

But as you can see, there is only the option to "delete pool". Therefore, the pool is not visible in the File Explorer.

[image: Pool]

`Get-StoragePool` shows "Read-only" in "OperationalStatus", as can be seen here:

[image: Power-Shell]

Now I am really wondering..... is there ANY way to get back at least some of the data on that drive? At least from my point of view, a "2-way-mirror" option seems kind of useless, if there is no way to get back the data if drives are failing.

Info on the pool: Initially created on Windows 7. Later, as I switched to Windows 10, I also "upgraded" the pool via the "Upgrade Pool" option in storage spaces. Furthermore, everything worked flawlessly until the drives died.

Hopefully someone is able to help me.

Comment: well this is a really crappy situation. There are a few ways to get back data. I would run a SMART test on the final HDD just to be sure that its actually safe to have running... but then go ahead and look for online data recovery tools. There are plenty and some are even free. Most are not free, however some are. I would honestly look into hirens bootcd. http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/ found here. You can use any one of a few tools that should get the job done fairly well. https://www.hiren.info/articles/recovery/hard-drive-data-recovery-freeware-programs an article that might help.

Comment: @Tomasito Thanks for working to improve [SU]. But note that when you embed (or “inline”) images into a post, you don’t need to download and re-upload the images — just edit the Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I was not able to mount the Pool on the last remaining disk. However, I ended up using EaseUs - it is not a freeware, but it did work quite well and even the directory tree was visible.

Thx to all!

Answer (score 0):

Only two tools I know that may be able to help:
ReclaiMe, http://www.storage-spaces-recovery.com/ and R-Studio http://www.r-studio.com/Unformat_Help/index.html?working_with_windows_storage_s.html.

In general the ReclaiMe tool is easiest to use.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

step 1 - Never use Storage Spaces Again - I used it for 6 years and my pools crashed 4 times - I was a stubborn person - now i realize how bad i had it.

your pool is read-only - which is good - that means apart from disk errors no more data errors can occur - that is a good thing

now download 'ReaclaiMe Storage Spaces Recovery', select all your disks that correspond to the pool you want to recover and select the pool that has GOOD Data - see the image below:

[image: ReclaiMe Strage Spaces Recovery]

to recover your files you can buy the software - Its $299 i believe
or
you can choose save-config then save the raw image file (you will need to choose a drive that can accommodate your pool) - this option is free as of writing this response
after it reclaims (now you know why they named the software Reclaime) you can use any image viewer to open and extract your files
good luck - and lesson for the day - do not go back to Windows Storage Spaces
Use Stalebit Drivepool